# Spring cloud contract: get params from previous response in scenario

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-contract

I wrote the scenario in spring cloud contract. On first request my app return token in response and second request should contain this token. Is there any possibility to pass a value from first response to second request?

Now I use in test another implementation of token generator, which returns predefined tokens, but I want to remove it and use real token generator.

Example of scenario:

1_getToken.groovy

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    description = 'receive token'
    request {
        method 'POST'
        url '/getToken'
        body("""
            {
            }
         """)
        headers {
            header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body("""
            {
                "token":"123"
            }
         """)
    }
}
```

2_addSmth.groovy

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    description = 'add somethingh'
    request {
        method 'POST'
        url '/addSmth'
        body("""
            {
                "token":"123",
                "value":"something"
            }
         """)
        headers {
            header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body("""
            {
            }
         """)
    }
}
```

i.e.
I want pass parameter "token" from first response to second request. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible at this point. You should hard code it. If you need very concrete values then most likely your contract tests are too complicated. Or even most likely they are no longer contract tests but you try to use contracts to verify the business behaviour